# How to controll fullPage.js vertical slider using mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

i am using this plugin 
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ 
and all the sections are working fine but i want that like vertical sliders horizontal sliders should also handle with mouse scroll. This is my last day to complete this project.
please tell me how to do this . . ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fullPage.js doesn't provide a way to do it. You would need to do it yourself or ask for a customization [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/#contact-page).

Answer (score -1):

I'd imagine you can attach en event listener to the slider to see if you are mousing over... For example,

Using jQuery...

```
$("#slider").mouseenter(function(){
   // halt the fullpage JS and the
})

$("#slider").mouseleave(function(){
   // resume the fullpage JS and the
})
```

Maybe this will point you in the direction, but is there any documentation regarding adding a slider with fullpage.js?

Comment: This is the main problem that they did not provide any documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js ? This is a bunch of documentation with a bunch of different settings. I don't have the time to crawl through it, but this might be what you are looking for.